# Nlog ${event-context:item=xxxx} not writing in logging database

Tags: c#, asp.net, nlog

I have a Nlog configuration that is basically this:

```
<target type="Database" name="database" connectionstring="<working connection string>">
  <commandText>insert into LogEntries ([Username], [Process], [TransactionCode], [WorkplaceId], [CreateDate], [Origin], [LogLevel], [Message], [Exception], [StackTrace]) values (@username, @process, @transactionCode, @workplaceId, @createDate, @origin, @logLevel, @message, @exception, @stackTrace);</commandText>

  <parameter name="@username" layout="${event-context:item=username}"/>
  <parameter name="@process" layout="${event-context:item=process}"/>
  <parameter name="@transactionCode" layout="${event-context:item=transactionCode}"/>
  <parameter name="@workplaceId" layout="${event-context:item=workplaceId}"/>
  <parameter name="@createDate" layout="${date}"/>
  <parameter name="@origin" layout="${callsite}"/>
  <parameter name="@logLevel" layout="${level}"/>
  <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}"/>
  <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:format=message}"/>
  <parameter name="@stackTrace" layout="${onexception: ${stacktrace}}"/>
</target>
```

The logging basically works, and the standard Nlog items are successfully written to the database, but the event-context items are written like empty string in the database.

I already checked the Properties item on the eventInfo object and it is filled correctly.

[image: Uknown Nlog state]

Anyone an idea on what I am missing? I am out of ideas of what it could be.

Comment: Interesting. The Level is set to Trace, but your break is on Info. Try matching the Levels?

Comment: The breakpoint is on a Logger.Trace() but it's behind the detailview. :) Adjusting the level has no effect on the issue (unfortunately). :(

Comment: I noticed this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967581/nlog-run-time-parameters-for-database-target) it had a more complicated issue. I'm curious if you change eventInfo.Properties to eventInfo.Parameters and give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, it was a bug (or a feature) in NLog. When writing to a 'target' in NLog asynchronously the original `LogEventInfo` that is written is added to the `Parameters` collection of a new `LogEventInfo`, thus the `Properties` collection where the `{event-context}` gets its values from is empty (because it is a new object). Resulting in the empty strings written to the database.

So, in order to solve this I added this function to << NLog 2.1 Source >>\Targets\Target.cs:

```
    private void MergeEventProperties(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        foreach (var item in logEvent.Parameters)
        {
            if (item.GetType() == typeof(LogEventInfo))
            {

                foreach (var propertyItem in ((LogEventInfo)item).Properties)
                {
                    logEvent.Properties.Remove(propertyItem.Key);
                    logEvent.Properties.Add(propertyItem);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in the function `protected virtual void Write(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)` I changed this code

```
        try
        {
            this.Write(logEvent.LogEvent);
            logEvent.Continuation(null);
        }
```

into this:

```
        try
        {
            MergeEventProperties(logEvent.LogEvent);

            this.Write(logEvent.LogEvent);
            logEvent.Continuation(null);
        }
```

After that, my values were written to the database.

I hope it helps other people who are having this issue.

Comment: How could this be a feature? Surely it's a bug? Have you reported it on the issue tracker: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues

Answer (score 1):

You have to fill in the LogEvent.Properties manually, or else all event-context items will render ''. These are not auto generated

https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer

event-context has been changed to event-properties in the NLog documentation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the fix. This issue has evolved slightly since your original positing.

After chasing down all the github patches ([334](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/334), [331](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/331), [371](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/371)) related to this problem and checking that they haven't been reversed, I've discovered that `${event-context:item=x}` doesn't seem to work properly anymore but `${event-properties:item=x}` does. To be fair they did mention that context is deprecated. So change your NLog.config to use `event-properties` is my advice.

Oh and I'm on NLog v4.1.0 and NLog.Extended v4.0.0.1 in case this crops up in the future.