# Programmatically configure NLog

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

i have these four parameters that return nothing to database :
Why this is happening and how to solve it ?

This is the full code :

https://www.codepile.net/pile/z1lol0Gb

Database is here :

https://www.codepile.net/pile/01JgbjXV

Part of my code

```
var dbTarget = new DatabaseTarget ();
dbTarget.ConnectionString = @"data source=.;initial catalog=Database5;user id=App;password=App;";
dbTarget.CommandText =
    @"insert into Logs (Level,CallSite,Type,Message,StackTrace,InnerException,AdditionalInfo) values (
         @level,
         @callSite,
         @type,
         @message,
         @stackTrace,
         @innerException,
         @additionalInfo
         );";
dbTarget.Parameters.Add (new DatabaseParameterInfo ("@level", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout ("${level}")));
dbTarget.Parameters.Add (new DatabaseParameterInfo ("@callSite", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout ("${callsite}")));
dbTarget.Parameters.Add (new DatabaseParameterInfo ("@type", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout ("${exception:format=type}")));
dbTarget.Parameters.Add (new DatabaseParameterInfo ("@message", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout ("${exception:format=message}")));
dbTarget.Parameters.Add (new DatabaseParameterInfo ("@stackTrace", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout ("${${exception:format=stackTrace}}")));
dbTarget.Parameters.Add (new DatabaseParameterInfo ("@innerException", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout ("${exception:format=:innerFormat=ShortType,Message,Method:MaxInnerExceptionLevel=1:InnerExceptionSeparator}")));
dbTarget.Parameters.Add (new DatabaseParameterInfo ("@additionalInfo", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout ("${message}")));
```

I have the same database that exist here :

https://knightcodes.com/.net/2016/05/25/logging-to-a-database-wth-nlog.html

This how they look in database

[image]

Database should look like this :
[image]

Comment: Could you show us your full code about c#?

Comment: i added now the important part, i can't post all the code because stackoverflow warn about " adding just code "

Comment: PS there is no need to do `new SimpleLayout`. You could just do: `new DatabaseParameterInfo("@level", "${level}")`

Comment: @JamesFallon please don't badger people in the comments. It's not acceptable behaviour. People will help if and when they can.

Answer (score 1):

You need to proper log your exception.

You code shows:

```
Logger logger1 = LogManager.GetLogger ("Logger1");
// Log something..
logger1.Error("Test Logger1");
```

but the `Exception` should be the first argument, see [How to log exceptions in NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-log-exceptions)

```
Logger logger1 = LogManager.GetLogger ("Logger1");
// Log something..
logger1.Error(new Exception("my error"), "Test Logger1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner exception can be empty so you can have empty values in your DB (but you must verify if it will save if inner exception is present). As for other properties I don't think someone can help you with sample you provided. Problem seems to lay in exception handling and using logger.
However I can't verify this with your sample. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967581/nlog-run-time-parameters-for-database-target) is problem that seems similar to yours. You can also read about [layour renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Exception-Layout-Renderer) and look for answers on NLog wiki. If you are not already doing this consider using [NLog config](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file) file to have everything concerning configuration in one place.

Comment: i have the same database that exist here https://knightcodes.com/.net/2016/05/25/logging-to-a-database-wth-nlog.html

Comment: @JamesFallon What we need to know is the input that produced those lines. As mr_cysio says: if exception is not given, the fields will be empty. Also, not every exception has an inner exception. Much more interesting is the line that's only half in the screenshot: It has a stacktrace but the other fields empty. That's a hint that there in fact _has_ been an exception but not all fields have been filled.

Comment: this the exception

  try
            {
                int zero = 0;
                int result = 5 / zero;
            }
            catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
            {